# Csv writer escape semicolon python

Tags: python-3.x, csv, escaping

This is the code that I use to generate a csv file.

```
with open("Output/output.csv", "w", newline='', encoding='utf-8') as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    writer.writerow({"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0"})
```

This is the csv file:

[image]

How can I put all the words in the same cell, treating the `;` as a normal char?

Comment: This is not related to the way Python writes the file.

You need to change the the delimiter in the application you are using to view the CSV file.